# Nullpointer Exception When Intent used in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem relating Intent.

Class A

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),JobOffer.class);
i.putExtra("From",aryListBean.get(arg2).getUser());
i.putExtra("StartDate",aryListBean.get(arg2).getStartDate());
i.putExtra("DueDate",aryListBean.get(arg2).getEndDate());
startActivity(i);
```

Class B

```
 Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
      String user=b.getString("From");
      String startdate=b.getString("StartDate");
      String duedate=b.getString("DueDate");
      ArrayList<String> hr_offerdet=b.getStringArrayList("AryHrOffer");

    tvUser.setText("   "+user);
    tvStarDate.setText("   "+startdate);
    tvDueDate.setText("   "+duedate);
```

Class C: back button to Class B

Now Here I have send Data Successfully to Class A to Class B. I get Data to class B,now when I move to class C from Class B, and again came back to class B,there is Nullpointer Exception. Have you any diff way to solve this ? please help

Comment: It happen when you back from C to B at that Bundle is null . you have to put condition

Comment: you can save this data in shared preferences and then reuse it whenever you want for example, if you get confused with intents...

Comment: Should B not still be running and have all it's data?
When you need data from C to B, use a ResultIntent.

Comment: do you simply use the default back button behaviour in Class C or do you start the B Activity from C when the back button is pressed?

Comment: where you have passed "AryHrOffer" while starting intent?

Comment: @Daler Why do you recommend such an overly complicated, resource wasting approach when there is no need for it?

Comment: @Nirav Who told you that the original poster will be happy if the exception is avoided? Don't you think he would want to have his Intent data at hand?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Also, do you start C using `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: @ClassStacker, didnt know that using shared preferences is complicated though, shared preferences uses almost in every app, how it can be so resource wasting.. do you have any articles about its resource wasting?

Comment: @Daler Wouldn't you agree that storing something in XML format (redundantly!) on a flash memory file system with limited life time (write cycles) is a waste of resources as compared to the well-working Android way of passing intent extras in memory? Sure almost every app uses SharedPreferences, but hopefully not to pass non-persistent data from one Activity to another. Each tool has its domain, and SharedPreferences is not the right tool to pass temporary app state data between Activities.

Comment: @ClassStacker, +1... will keep it in mind, didnt know about it really.

Comment: @Daler Thanks. There is a reason why in API 9, `SharedPreferences.Editor.apply()` was introduced in addition to `commit()`. While the functionality is the same, `apply()` automatically runs in the background such that the main/UI thread is not blocked by the write operation. I guess many people had started to use SharedPreferences extensively by then... ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker, another +1 for this info..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you were not able to pass the arraylist with key "AryHrOffer".

Also, you should always check first if the bundle exists.

eg. `if(b!=null){ //... }`

Then, all classes that needs to open Activity B should pass the parameters needed if they are really required else ignore if the bundle is null.

EDIT:

After re-reading your problem I noticed you stated that
 "..and again **came back** to class B,there is Nullpointer Exception"

The problem might be not in the passing of extras in intent but something on your Activity B's onResume.

Comment: Kudos. You read the code and found the problem, instead of blindly suggesting questionable workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: please provide logcat and on which of your instructions you have the NullPointer.

You have to check these things:

```
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String user = b.getString("From");
    String startdate = b.getString("StartDate");
    String duedate = b.getString("DueDate");
    ArrayList < String > hr_offerdet = b.getStringArrayList("AryHrOffer");

    tvUser.setText("   " + user);
    tvStarDate.setText("   " + startdate);
    tvDueDate.setText("   " + duedate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to check whether `bundle` is `null` or not.

```
if(b!=null){

 // your code

}
```

Comment: Who told you that the original poster will be happy if the exception is avoided? Don't you think he would want to have his Intent data at hand?